# Simulating IIS App Pool Identity in ASP.Net Core Integration Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm attempting to write integration tests for an ASP.Net Core 3.1 API that I'm writing. I'm using the WebApplicationFactory<> class in order to create an HttpClient for calling into the API.

```
_Factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>()
            .WithWebHostBuilder(b =>
            {
                b.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddAuthentication("Test")
                        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, MyAuthHandler>("Test", options => { });
                    RegisterTestServices(services);
                });
            });
```

With:

```
public class MyAuthHandler: AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public MyAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }
    protected override  Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var claims = new[] {new Claim("preferred_username", "mchu")};
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Test");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, "Test");

        var result = AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

This successfully allows me to retrieve an HttpClient that can call out to my endpoints (decorated with [Authorize]) so I don't get 401 errors. However, some of my tests are failing due to permissions problems upon attempting to access network shares.

In an actual IIS deployment, our application pool would be using an identity that has read/write access to those shares.

Is there anything I can do to ensure that my API code runs with permissions that can access those protected resources? Our existing integration test code (for non-ASP.Net Core code--this is a conversion) gets around this problem by simply performing the particular operations in an administrator impersonation context. I'm fine with doing that for these new tests, as well.

However, without yet understanding a whole lot about WebApplicationFactory<> (or any bit of the ASP.Net Core middleware pipeline, really), I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core doesn't implement impersonation. Apps run with the app's identity for all requests, using app pool or process identity. If the app should perform an action on behalf of a user, use WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated in a terminal inline middleware in Startup.Configure. Run a single action in this context and then close the context.

More details you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation)

Comment: Thank you. I did find this article in my attempts so solve this problem, and my solution is pretty much as you described. The only difference is that I configure the middleware only when using a custom "Testing" development environment, since, in production, the proper behavior is provided by IIS's hosting. I am curious, however, as to what "normal" use cases are such that the course of most ASP.Net Core integration test code doesn't require the permissions of the app pool user that may be different from the permissions of the user running the test.